# Delete repeated subsequent entries from 2D list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following list:

```
p =\
 [(58.5, -4.5),
 (67.5, -4.5),
 (76.5, -4.5),
 (76.5, 4.5),
 (67.5, 4.5),
 (58.5, 4.5),
 (67.5, 4.5),
 (58.5, 4.5),
 (58.5, 13.5),
 (49.5, 13.5),
 (40.5, 13.5),
 (49.5, 13.5),
 (40.5, 13.5),
 (40.5, 22.5),
 (31.5, 22.5),
 (22.5, 22.5),
 (31.5, 22.5),
 (22.5, 22.5),
 (22.5, 31.5),
 (13.5, 31.5),
 (4.5, 31.5),
 (13.5, 31.5),
 (4.5, 31.5),
 (4.5, 40.5),
 (-4.5, 40.5),
 (-4.5, 31.5),
 (-4.5, 22.5),
 (-4.5, 31.5),
 (-4.5, 22.5),
 (-4.5, 13.5),
 (-4.5, 22.5),
 (-4.5, 13.5),
 (-4.5, 4.5),
 (-4.5, 13.5),
 (-4.5, 4.5),
 (-4.5, -4.5),
 (4.5, -4.5),
 (13.5, -4.5),
 (4.5, -4.5),
 (13.5, -4.5),
 (22.5, -4.5),
 (13.5, -4.5),
 (22.5, -4.5),
 (31.5, -4.5),
 (22.5, -4.5),
 (31.5, -4.5),
 (40.5, -4.5),
 (31.5, -4.5),
 (40.5, -4.5),
 (49.5, -4.5),
 (40.5, -4.5),
 (49.5, -4.5),
 (58.5, -4.5),
 (49.5, -4.5),
 (58.5, -4.5)]
```

As you will see, there are a few repetitive coordinates:
[image]

I only what to keep the first appearance of a coordinate and delete all the subsequent repetitions of the same coordinate:

[image]

Is there any clever way to do that in Python?

Comment: [`np.unique(arr, axis=1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` to filter the duplicates (`p` is your list from the question):

```
seen = set()
out = []
for coord in p:
    if coord not in seen:
        out.append(coord)
        seen.add(coord)

from pprint import pprint

pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[(58.5, -4.5),
 (67.5, -4.5),
 (76.5, -4.5),
 (76.5, 4.5),
 (67.5, 4.5),
 (58.5, 4.5),
 (58.5, 13.5),
 (49.5, 13.5),
 (40.5, 13.5),
 (40.5, 22.5),
 (31.5, 22.5),
 (22.5, 22.5),
 (22.5, 31.5),
 (13.5, 31.5),
 (4.5, 31.5),
 (4.5, 40.5),
 (-4.5, 40.5),
 (-4.5, 31.5),
 (-4.5, 22.5),
 (-4.5, 13.5),
 (-4.5, 4.5),
 (-4.5, -4.5),
 (4.5, -4.5),
 (13.5, -4.5),
 (22.5, -4.5),
 (31.5, -4.5),
 (40.5, -4.5),
 (49.5, -4.5)]
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this:
`list(set(p))`

Edit: To preserve the order, do:
`[c for i, c in enumerate(p) if c not in p[:i]]`